# Making with Objective-C a database in which the user could add information to it

Tags: objective-c, database, master-detail

I'd want to create a growing database in which the user could add new info in this case different integers and I don't really know how. I've started a "Master Detail" application but when I add different elements to the table they to be mutable and different. So I want the code to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you really need to start with the basics;  the introduction to Objective-C followed by intros to iOS or Mac OS X development.  Work through the basics first.

Then grab yourself a guide to Core Data.

---

> Would you mid giving me a tutorial or something to learn it

A bit broad of a question for StackOverflow.   I'd suggest you start at either of the Getting Started guides specific to [iOS development](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started) or [Mac OS X development](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started), as you fancy.

In terms of cars, your question would translate to "How do I add a turbocharger to my engine?".  If you don't have a solid foundation in how to maintain and build cars, any answer someone might give will be impossible to understand.

Comment: He probably should start with an intro to SQLite.

Comment: Would you mid giving me a tutorial or something to learn it

Comment: I'd skip SQLite and go straight to Core Data.  SQLite is deceptively easy, but I've never seen even a relatively experienced developer do SQLite right the first time. Or the second.  Or, typically, the third.  Leverage Core Data and you gain the experience of a dedicated team that has been doing SQLite for ~8 years, including working with the author, to make it optimal, correct, and highly tuned to the platform.  Anything else is a waste of time save for the most esoteric of situations.